# Can I use Twilio video js sdk's rtc stream and convert it into an HLS or DASH?

Tags: twilio, twilio-video, shaka, eme

I've been looking for a while now and scanning the Twilio documentation, I haven't found any resource pointing to this, but I'm hoping someone has any ideas if this can be achieved.

My end goal would be to be able to use twilio video js' underlying webRTC and load up that stream into a media server that I could use to convert into HLS. I would then use the `HLS/DASH` and implement EME and load it up to a `shaka` video player.